# Can resize Kendo bar chart to fill screen but not pie or gauge

Tags: asp.net, razor, charts, kendo-ui

I have the following style applied to my charts when they are clicked, which hides all other Div elements and makes the clicked one look "full screen":

```
<style>
     .hidden {
                display: none;
             }
     .overlay {
                position: absolute !important;
                top: 0 !important;
                left: 0 !important;
                bottom: 0 !important;
                right: 0 !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                height: 100% !important;
              }
    </style>
```

Using the following:

```
var fullScreen = 0;

    $('#VehicleStatus').click(function () {

    if (fullScreen == 0) {
        var position = $("#VehicleStatus").position();
        var leftCoord = position.left;
        var rightCoord = position.right;
        var topCoord = position.top;
        var bottomCoord = position.bottom;
        $(".all").addClass("hidden");
        $("#VehicleStatus").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#VehicleStatus").addClass("overlay");
        fullScreen = 1;
    }
    else {

        $(".all").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#VehicleStatus").removeClass("overlay");
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("position", "relative");
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("top", topCoord);
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("bottom", bottomCoord);
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("left", leftCoord);
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("right", rightCoord);
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("width", "500px");
        $("#VehicleStatus").css("height", "280px");
        fullScreen = 0;

    }
})
```

But when I use the ID of one of my Pie charts or Gauges they dont work. The gauge just goes to the top left of the screen and remains its original size and the pie chart just removes everything from the page.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call refresh, please see my example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KendoPieChart.aspx.cs"     Inherits="Demo.KendoPieChart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .smallChart{ width: 200px;}
    .bigChart{ width: 900px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="chartContainer" class="smallChart">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="resize">Resize</div>
</form>


<script>
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Break-up of Spain Electricity Production for 2008"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%"
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "pie",
            data: [{
                category: "Hydro",
                value: 22
            }, {
                category: "Solar",
                value: 2
            }, {
                category: "Nuclear",
                value: 49
            }, {
                category: "Wind",
                value: 27
            }]
        }]
    });


    $('#resize').click(function() {
        $('#chartContainer').toggleClass('smallChart');
        $('#chartContainer').toggleClass('bigChart');


        //$("#chart").redraw();
        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
        chart.refresh();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's not the issue. The charts are set to read the datasource every few seconds which refreshes the chart anyway. Plus that wouldnt really explain why it works for the bar charts and not the others

Comment: Refreshing isnt the issue. Also im using Razor not aspx

Comment: If resizing isn't your issue then what is? The title of your question is "Can resize Kendo bar chart to fill screen but not pie or gauge"

Comment: I said refreshing isnt the issue. Resizing is. Regardless of the refresh the pie and gauges arent behaving like the bar charts. Please read my original post again.

Comment: I don't think you ran my code, it's a Pie chart with button for toggling between a small and large graph size.